# Lang's *Algebra*: definition of $F[\alpha]$ and why it's an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, definition, integral-domain

I am reading Lang's *Algebra*, namely the chapter about Fields.

1. The first thing which confused me is the following: how he defines $F[\alpha]$? Later he defines this as the smallest subfield of $E$ which contains both $F$ and $\alpha$. But in this context it is not clear what is $F[\alpha]$. Can anyone explain this, please?
2. Suppose we defined $F[\alpha]$ in some way. How it follows that this is integral domain (Lang calls it entire ring)?

Would be very grateful for help!
[image]

Comment: It's just the image of the homomorphism $K[X]\to E$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I also had the same idea. But what is the structure of $F[\alpha]$? And why is it integral domain?

Comment: For one, it's occuring inside $E$, a field.

Comment: It is a subring of a field, which has no zero divisors.

Comment: @Bernard, this makes sense! Thanks a lot for clear answer!

Comment: B.t.w., $F[\alpha]$ is a field if and only if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: @Bernard, Yes If I'm not mistaken I've learnt this from Lang's book. But what is the structure of $F[\alpha]$? Could you give detailed answer,please? I'll definitely appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean with *structure of* $F[\alpha]$?

Comment: @Bernard, I mean how it elements look like. Is there uniqueness of representation in $F[\alpha]$? I begin to study field theory couple days ago and it seems to me very interesting but some moments of Lang's book are quite difficult and would like to see some examples. For example, in ring $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ we have no uniqueness of representation since we can write $1$ also as $(\sqrt{2})^2-1$. Am I right?

Comment: BTW, I see that most of your answers are dedicated to algebra. maybe you can give advice on some book of field theory with examples?

Comment: The elements of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)$ are uniquely represented as $x+y\sqrt 2$ ($x,y\in \mathbf Q$). More generally, if $\alpha$ is algebraic and has minimal polynomial of degree $d$, an element of $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ is uniquely represented as a polynomial in $\alpha$ of degree $<d$ ( a remainder when we divide by the minimal polynomial. As to books I could recommend, there's precisely Lang's *Algebra* (I admit it's a a little tough – to be read with pencil and paper). Also Bourbaki's *Algebra*, Ch. V, *Commutative fields* – this one is complete.

Comment: @Bernard, why it is obvious that that elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ could be represented in unique way as polynomial of degree $<d$, where $d$-degree of $\alpha$. Could you explain in rigorous way or maybe give a reference?

Comment: It's easy : let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of \alpha$ and $f(x) be any polynomial. By Euclidean division, you obtain unique polynomial $q(x),\,r(x)$ such that $$f(x)=q(x)p(x)+r(x),\quad \deg r<\deg p.$$ Now plug in the value $x=\alpha$ to get $f(\alpha)=r(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

Lang makes the following definition in Chapter 2, $\S$1 (third paragraph, page 90, third edition):

> Let $A$ be a subring of a ring $B$. Let $S$ be a subset of $B$ commuting with $A$; in other words, we have $sa = as$ for all $a \in A$ and $s \in S$. We denote by $A[S]$ the set of all elements
>   $$
> \sum a_{i_1,\dots,i_n} s_1^{i_1} \cdots s_n^{i_n},
> $$
>   the sum ranging over a finite number of $n$-tuples $(i_1,\dots,i_n)$ of integers $\geq 0$, and $a_{i_1,\dots,i_n} \in A$, $s_1,\dots,s_n \in S$.

---

This gives you a definition of $F[\alpha]$. Take $A = F$, $B = E$ and $S = \{ \alpha \}$ to get that $F[\alpha]$ is the set of all elements
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \alpha^i,
$$
the sum ranging over all integers $n \geq 0$, and $a_i \in F$.

---

Why is $F[\alpha]$ an integral domain? This is because every element in $F[\alpha]$ is also an element of $E$: notice that $A[S] \subset B$ by the definition of $A[S]$.

Since $E$ is a field, it is an integral domain. Hence, any subring of $E$ is also an integral domain. In particular, $F[\alpha]$ is an integral domain.